# Check if user has IMPERSONATE permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2014

I would like to check if the user is able to perform "EXECUTE AS" statement. It can be "sa" or granted explicitly. Any way to know exactly?

Comment: Have a look at HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME () https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-perms-by-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DenisRubashkin if you create an answer, I'll accept it